# C# time format to use "a.m." and "p.m." instead of AM/PM?

Tags: c#, date, time, string-formatting

I can't find information on how to use the CultureInfo classes (or whatever is needed) to display a formatted time in "a.m." and "p.m." (note the periods) instead of the default AM and PM.

First, what culture info surrounds the use of "a.m."/"p.m." instead of AM/PM? Is there a way to do this using format providers and not a hack such as string replacements? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at what's available in the [`DateTimeFormatInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) exposed by the `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat` property. Its `AMDesignator` and `PMDesignator` properties let you set the strings used for those values.

Take special note of the Remarks section of that link, in particular:

> The application can replace standard
>   patterns with custom patterns by
>   setting the associated properties of a
>   writable DateTimeFormatInfo object. To
>   determine if a DateTimeFormatInfo
>   object is writable, the application
>   should use the IsReadOnly property.

If you pull CultureInfo and its child info objects from the current, invariant, or a specific culture, they tend to be read-only by default. Be prepared to use the `Clone()` method on those objects to retrieve writable copies that you can return and use to set format strings.

Once you have a `DateTimeFormatInfo` with the AM/PM properties set as desired, you can supply that as the `IFormatProvider` used by methods like `String.Format()` and `Object.ToString()`.